# Probability theory regarding expected values as well as L sets

Tags: probability-theory

I am required to prove the following:

Let $L_1$ be the space of real valued random variables on $(\Omega; A; P )$ which
have finite expectation $E(|X|) < \infty$ and let $L_2$ be the space of real valued random variables such that $E(X^2) < \infty$. Show that $L_2 \subset L_1.$

I have realized that the Markov and Chebyshev theorems need to be used, as well as a possible indicator function(I have been told). I am unsure how to actually begin, since no further clarification has been given.

May someone please assist me on how this may be proved?

Answer (score 1):

$E|X|=E|X|I_{|X|<1}+E|X|I_{|X|\geq 1}\leq E1+EX^{2}I_{|X|\geq1}\leq 1+EX^{2}<\infty$.

I have used the fact that $|X| \leq X^{2}$ when $|X| \geq 1$.